# Problem with Partitioning when installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 and when the partition starts, it never completes. I get errors like `(Ubiquity: '3660' gtk CRITICAL  **: gtk_widget_draw: assertion '!widget - >priv- all oc_needed failed)` about 25 times, then after other statements I get: `(Sep 22 01:28:0` Ubuntu AptDaemon: Info - Quitting due to inactivity)`plus a final statement similar but saying`(Quitting was requested)`. I assume the latter was because I initiated the quit.

After re-booting to Windows 7 it does a Disk Check, but finds no errors. My machine is a Dell XPS, 12 GB memory, two 1.5 TB hard drives, with the C: drive with 500 to 700 GB free, depending on which of the two install tries I recorded.

I have two 1.5 TB drives in my computer. Neither is partitioned. Windows was not hibernated (was not even running) and did not need chkdsk before the Ubuntu install attempt. I assume Windows 7 uses the entire C: primary partition, which is the entire drive space. The instructions for installing Ubuntu did not mention shrinking the Windows partition. During the install process I used the sliding bar to allocate 100+ GB for the Ubuntu partition and clicked Install Now. When it started to partition the disk for the Ubuntu install, it never got any further, giving me the error messages mentioned.

Comment: Did you use Windows to shrink Windows partition to make unallocated space. Is Windows hibernated or NTFS partition needing chkdsk? Gparted may give warning is you create partitions in advance with gparted. How many primary partitions do you have if MBR, or is system UEFI with gpt partitions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any live CD of ubuntu to fixed the problem when get a window for installing ubuntu there select

> install now

and may open partition editor like GParted software! and right now edit your hardisk.